# spring security only answer the thymeleaf's action,and instead, return 302 for nomal form's action

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

Here I met a problem with Spring Security.
I used the Spring Boot to build a Web Application, and try to bring in Spring Security for authentication and authorization.
I want to realize a login page,but I found out that spring security always return a 302 response.
here's the codes associated with these problem.

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "tb_user")
public class User implements UserDetails{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String account;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;


    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Role> roles;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Role> roles = this.getRoles();
        for(Role role : roles) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return account;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}

@Data
@Entity(name = "tb_role")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByAccount(String account);
}

public class CustomUserService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByAccount(s);
        if(user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User doesn't exist");
        }
        return user;
    }
}

@Configuration
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    UserDetailsService customUserService() {
        return new CustomUserService();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new PasswordEncoder() {
            @Override
            public String encode(CharSequence charSequence) {
                return charSequence.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matches(CharSequence charSequence, String s) {
                return s.equals(charSequence.toString());
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserService());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/plugins/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll();
    }
}

<form  action="/login" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username"><br/>
    <input type="password" name="password"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

However, when I added thymeleaf's action in the login form,  the problem was solved,and every things goes OK.just like this.

```
    <form th:action="@{/login}" action="/login" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="username"><br/>
        <input type="password" name="password"><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
```

Now I'm confused.
Should it must match the thymeleaf?
but it doesn't make any sense.
that must be something wrong.
I hope somebody could give me an answer.
please.

Comment: Please post the relevant codes here in question itself. do not give image of codes, that too as a link unless its absolute necessary.

Comment: thanks for reminding me.the question has been edited

Comment: where is the bean?

Comment: the question has been edited.But，I don't think there's something wrong with the bean, because I can enter the index page with correct account and get wrong message with uncorrect account.It tells that the security is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thymeleaf automatically adds  `<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="...."/>` when you have a `<form />` with `th:action` as a property (and spring security is set up properly).  When you leave off `th:action` the csrf is missing and spring rejects your form.

Comment: then what is the value of the attribute "value".And where it came from.How can I fixed it using the plain <form/> action.To do so,I need to know the value.